# Python Tkinter dependent drop down

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, dropdown

i trying to do the following:
i have two lists, matching each other. i want to create a dropdown list with tkinter with one list, and return the match from the other list. the values in the lists match injectivly one to each other.
i want the second list match to be a label or entry without choosing it like with two dependent drop down list. i've tried the following, but it only return OD.
thanks from advance
Avraham

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
root = tkinter.Tk()
options  = tkinter.StringVar(root)

pipe_size = [
    '1/8', '1/4', '3/8', '1/2', '3/4', '1', '1 1/4', '1 1/2', '2', '2 1/2', '3', '3',
    '1/2', '4', '5', '6', '8', '10', '12', '14', '16', '18', '20', '22', '24', '26', '28', '30', 
    '32', '34', '36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46', '48', '52', '56', '60'
]
OD_mm = [
    '10.3', '13.7', '17.1', '21.3', '26.7', '33.4', '42.2', '48.3', '60.3', '73', '88.9', 
    '101.6', '114.3', '141.3', '168.3', '219.1', '273.1', '323.9', '355.6', '406.4', '457.2', 
    '508', 
    '559', '610', '660', '711', '762', '813', '884', '914', '965', '1016', '1067', '1118', '1168', 
    '1219', '1321'
]

str_out=tkinter.StringVar(root)
str_out.set("OD")


def callback(eventObject):
    abc = eventObject.widget.get()
    car = pipe_size_list.get()
    index=pipe_size.index(car)
    str_out.config(values=OD_mm[index])
    str_out.set(OD_mm_str.get())


pipe_size_list = ttk.Combobox(root, width=37, value=(pipe_size))
pipe_size_list.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=2, sticky='w')


OD_mm_str = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable = str_out)

OD_mm_str.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

OD_mm_str.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', callback)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You bind `<<ComboboxSelected>>` on wrong widget, it should be bound on `pipe_size_list` instead.

Comment: Also `str_out.set(oo_mm_str.get())` should be changed to `str_out.set(oo_mm[index])` and `str_out.config(values=OD_mm[index])` should be removed.